# simulation of Randomized distributed algorithms

Tags: distributed-systems, simulation

I want to implement various Randomized Distributed algorithms for MIS, Broadcast, Coloring in Radio Networks. I want use very high level language or any simulator for this. Please suggest on this.

Comment: This answer does not have an answer in its current state. You need to add more requirements and even then, it's likely to be very subjective. Just use what you are comfortable with first; if you run into problems, adapt.